# Simple way to replace context menu

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer

How to replace the context menu when an object is selected?

Currently I am trying this based on the API and the Autodesk.ADN.Viewing.Extension.ContextMenu.js example from Philippe Leefsma.

```
var contextMenu = new Autodesk.Viewing.UI.ObjectContextMenu(viewer);

contextMenu.buildMenu(Autodesk.Viewing.AGGREGATE_SELECTION_CHANGED_EVENT, [{ title: 'This is a menu item', target: function () { alert('Menu item clicked'); } }]);

viewer.setContextMenu(contextMenu);
```

Comment: Can you be more specific what you mean by "replace" ... ? Do you want to replace the items of the menu by your owns, append some more options, replace the context menu itself ...

Comment: I would like replace the items of the menu with my own. I can append the menu with registerContextMenuCallback, but I could not get removing the preset context menu items to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be pretty straightforward to replace all menu items with your own ... Take a look [there](https://github.com/Developer-Autodesk/library-javascript-viewer-extensions/blob/master/src/Autodesk.ADN.Viewing.Extension.ContextMenu/Autodesk.ADN.Viewing.Extension.ContextMenu.js) for a full sample

```
Autodesk.ADN.Viewing.Extension.AdnContextMenu.prototype.buildMenu =

      function (event, status) {

          //completely disable native menu 
          //var menu =  Autodesk.Viewing.Extensions.ViewerObjectContextMenu.prototype.buildMenu.call(this, event, status);

          //and sneak your own ...
          var menu = []

          menu.push({
            title: "Dude menu item",
            target: function () {
                alert('Dude I was clicked!');
            }
          })

          return menu;
      };
```

Comment: Can you please accept as solution or mention how the answer doesn't address your need? It's important for us and other programmers to flag the answers as "solution" when they actually solve the problem. Thanks